# Variável sem valor pl/sql

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Eu tentei executar esse pl/sql mas não funcionou

```
declare
v teste%rowtype;
begin
v.ra;
select ra into v.ra from teste where nome = 'Danilo';
dbms_output.put_line(v.ra);
end;
```

depois de muito tempo decidi atribuir um valor a ele e depois alterar o valor com o select e funcionou

```
declare
v teste%rowtype;
begin
v.ra:= 0;
select ra into v.ra from teste where nome = 'Danilo';
dbms_output.put_line(v.ra);
end;
```

Queria saber o porque dele dar erro com o valor null e se seria uma boa pratica sempre atribuir o valor de 0 para todas as variáveis antes de qualquer coisa

Answer (score 1):

O problema neste caso não está relacionado com o fato de `v.ra` ser ou não `NULL`, trata-se apenas de um erro de sintaxe.

Muito provavelmente a mensagem de erro que recebeu é a seguinte:

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 1: PLS-00221: 'RA' is not a procedure or is
>   undefined ORA-06550: line 3, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Muitas vezes as mensagens de erro não são muito claras na razão do erro, mas neste caso a razão parece ser clara: `v.ra;` não é um procedimento ou bloco de código que possa ser executado.

Não percebi bem o seu objectivo com essa instrução, mas a variável `v` tem um tipo que depende da estrutura da tabela `teste`, pelo que `v.ra` deverá ser provavelmente um NUMBER, CHAR, BLOB, DATE ou outro tipo habitualmente usado para definir uma coluna de uma tabela. Não será pois possível "executar" a expressão `v.ra;`

Quando alterou a instrução para `v.ra := 0` passou ou compilador uma instrução que ele entende. Neste caso, trata-se de uma atribuição. Daí o seu código ter executado sem erro.

Para mostrar que o problema não tinha mesmo a ver com o NULL, veja o seguinte bloco anónimo, sem a atribuição, funcionando no [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3c9a/5)

```
declare v teste%rowtype;
begin
select ra into v.ra from teste where nome = 'Danilo';
dbms_output.put_line(v.ra);
end
;
/
```